# parse_obj in Pydantic with field that is a heterogeneous tuple?

Tags: python, pydantic

In Pydantic the class

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
      bar : str
      baz : int
```

Can be imported from a tuple `["aaa", 3]` by doing something like:

```
[**{key: tr[i] for i, key in enumerate(fields.__TraceItem__.keys())})]
```

It can also be converted from `{bar: "aaa", baz: 3}` using `parse_obj`. But how do you import something that combines the two? In other words, given the classes

```
class Bar(BaseModel):
      f1: str
      f2: float
      f3: Boolean

class Qux(BaseModel):
      field1: str
      field2: float
      field3: list[Bar]
```

How do I convert the following JSON into the `Qux` object above?

```py
{
    field1: "bar",
    field2: 3.14,
    field3: [
        ["aaa", 2.71, True],
        ["bbb", -1, False]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just pointing it out that `["aaa", 3]` is a list, not a tuple. Also your field3 in your example is a list of lists. There is no tuple here, contrary to what's in your title.

Comment: What about transforming the elements of `field3` into a `dict` before passing the data to pydantic? Data can come in **any format** and it seems to me that there will be always cases where a transformation might be necessary before pydantic can accept the data. Pydantic supports parsing JSON data, but I believe it is designed for cases where the data closely resembles the pydantic models.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/).

[As pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605447/parse-obj-in-pydantic-with-field-that-is-a-heterogeneous-tuple#comment128288623_72605447), "*there will be always cases where a transformation might be necessary before pydantic can accept the data*", which is especially true for your JSON data that does not exactly match the model.

This

```
[["aaa", 2.71, True], ["bbb", -1, False]]
```

is a list of primitive values and it is definitely not the same type as

```
[
  {'f1': 'aaa', 'f2': 2.71, 'f3': True}, 
  {'f1': 'bbb', 'f2': -1.0, 'f3': False}
]
```

which more closely resembles a list of actual `Bar` objects.

For cases like that, you might need to implement the parsing yourself.

#### Option 1

Let `Bar` have a `validator` that parses a list of lists into a list of `Bar`'s.

```py
class Bar(BaseModel):
    f1: str
    f2: float
    f3: bool

class Qux(BaseModel):
    field1: str
    field2: float
    field3: list[Bar]

    @validator("field3", pre=True)
    def parse_field3_as_bar(cls, value):
        # If value is already a list[Bar], then return as-is
        if isinstance(value, list) and isinstance(value[0], Bar):
            return value
        # If not, try coercing into a list[Bar]
        # Expect value to be ex. [["aaa", 2.71, True], ["bbb", -1, False]]
        try:
            bar_fields = Bar.__fields__.keys()
            return [
                Bar(**dict(zip(bar_fields, triplet))) 
                for triplet in value
            ]
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError(f"Cannot convert to list[Bar]: {value!r}")
```

```
>>> from main import Bar, Qux
>>> d = {"field1": "bar", "field2": 3.14, "field3": [["aaa", 2.71, True], ['bbb', -1, False]]}
>>> q = Qux(**d)
>>> q
Qux(field1='bar', field2=3.14, field3=[Bar(f1='aaa', f2=2.71, f3=True), Bar(f1='bbb', f2=-1.0, f3=False)])
```

If the passed `value` is of the wrong data format:

```
>>> dx = {"field1": "bar", "field2": 3.14, "field3": [["not", "a"], ["list", "of", "Bar"], "values"]}
>>> q = Qux(**dx)
  ...
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Qux
field3
  Cannot convert to list[Bar]: [['not', 'a'], ['list', 'of', 'Bar'], 'values'] (type=value_error)
```

You mentioned `parse_obj` in your title, and I assume you mean the [`parse_obj`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#helper-functions) helper function.
It works just as well with that:

```py
>>> d = {"field1": "bar", "field2": 3.14, "field3": [["aaa", 2.71, True], ['bbb', -1, False]]}
>>> Qux.parse_obj(d)
Qux(field1='bar', field2=3.14, field3=[Bar(f1='aaa', f2=2.71, f3=True), Bar(f1='bbb', f2=-1.0, f3=False)])
```

#### Option 2

Let `Bar` have a `validator` same as **Option 1**, but with [`each_item=True`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) so that you can parse one list item at a time (one `triplet` at a time) into a `Bar` object:

```py
class Bar(BaseModel):
    f1: str
    f2: float
    f3: bool

class Qux(BaseModel):
    field1: str
    field2: float
    field3: list[Bar]

    @validator("field3", pre=True, each_item=True)
    def parse_field3_as_bar(cls, value):
        # If value is already a Bar, then return as-is
        if isinstance(value, Bar):
            return value
        # Try coercing value into a Bar
        # Expect value to be ex. ['aaa', 2.71, True]
        try:
            bar_fields = Bar.__fields__.keys()
            return Bar(**dict(zip(bar_fields, value)))
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("Cannot convert to Bar:", value)
```

```
>>> from main import Bar, Qux
>>> d = {"field1": "bar", "field2": 3.14, "field3": [["aaa", 2.71, True], ['bbb', -1, False]]}
>>> q = Qux(**d)
>>> q
Qux(field1='bar', field2=3.14, field3=[Bar(f1='aaa', f2=2.71, f3=True), Bar(f1='bbb', f2=-1.0, f3=False)])
```

If the passed `value` is of the wrong data format:

```
>>> from main import Bar, Qux
>>> dx = {"field1": "bar", "field2": 3.14, "field3": [["aaa", 2.71, True], 9999]}
>>> q = Qux(**dx)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Qux
field3 -> 1
  Cannot convert to Bar: 9999 (type=value_error)
```

You mentioned `parse_obj` in your title, and I assume you mean the [`parse_obj`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#helper-functions) helper function.
It works just as well with that:

```
>>> d = {"field1": "bar", "field2": 3.14, "field3": [["aaa", 2.71, True], ['bbb', -1, False]]}
>>> Qux.parse_obj(d)
Qux(field1='bar', field2=3.14, field3=[Bar(f1='aaa', f2=2.71, f3=True), Bar(f1='bbb', f2=-1.0, f3=False)])
```

---

As a side note, [I mentioned it already in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605447/parse-obj-in-pydantic-with-field-that-is-a-heterogeneous-tuple#comment128261781_72605447), you mention "*tuple*" in your question

> can be imported from a tuple `["aaa", 3]`

But that is *not* a tuple, nor do I see any tuples in any of your example code and input/output data. I'm not sure if you are aware, but in Python, a Tuple refers to a specific data type: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences.

What you have is basically a list of lists, and each sub-list is just list of other data types. (Which is why in my answer I refer to it as a `triplet`).

Comment: You point out that a list of primitives doesn't resemble the model but Pydantic and imply that that's why it doesn't work but I pointed out that you can in fact import a list of primitives without doing any special parsing. It's only when you want one of those objects to be a field in another object does everything break down.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a simpler approach, based off of [Gino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73009882/10521959) – add a class method on `Bar` to allow instantiating from an array, then call that method from a validator from `Qux`:

```py
from typing import List, Any
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Bar(BaseModel):
    f1: str
    f2: float
    f3: bool

    @classmethod
    def from_array(cls, values: List[Any]):
        """
        Returns instance of class from an array of values.

        NOTE: This method assumes all fields are present

        ALSO: A hackier implementation of this method:
            return cls(
                f1=values[0],
                f2=values[1],
                f3=values[2]
            )
        """
        model_data = {
            key: values[i]
            for i, key in enumerate(cls.__fields__.keys())
        }

        return cls.parse_obj(model_data)


class Qux(BaseModel):
    field1: str
    field2: float
    field3: List[Bar]

    @validator('field3', each_item=True, pre=True)
    def field3_from_array(cls, v: List[Any]):
        """
        Validator for field3 which can be represented as
        a list containing:
            - `Bar` objects
            - arrays (of Bar values)
            - dicts (of Bar objects)
        """
        if isinstance(v, Bar):
            return v
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            return Bar.from_array(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            return Bar.parse_obj(v)
```

Here's what it looks in action:

```
>>> data = {
...     "field1": "bar",
...     "field2": 3.14,
...     "field3": [
...         ["aaa", 2.71, True],
...         ["bbb", -1, False],
...         {"f1": "ccc", "f2": 3.0, "f3": True}
...     ]
... }

>>> Qux.parse_obj(data)
Qux(field1='bar',field2=3.14, field3=[Bar(f1='aaa', f2=2.71, f3=True), Bar(f1='bbb', f2=-1.0, f3=False), Bar(f1='ccc', f2=3.0, f3=True)])
```